# oauth token visual studio web test

Tags: visual-studio, load-testing, azure-application-insights

I am recording a visual studio web test for angularjs spa application. The application is getting data from web api application, passing oauth token for authentication. When I replay the recorded web test the oauth token is not being sent and the recorded tests are getting failed.

Please let me know how this can be fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to implement a custom WebTestRequestPlugin to pass authorization token.

```
public override void PreRequest(object sender, PreRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            var token = GetOAuthToken(1500, 1);
            var header = new WebTestRequestHeader("Authorization", token);
            e.Request.Headers.Add(header);
        }
```

Comment: Could you post the source for `GetOAuthToken()`? Just curious. Thanks!